# forwarding parameters in tag dispatching

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding

I am writing function for binding SQL parameters and want to use tag dispatching. So I wrote this code:

```
class OraclePreparedStatement
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void bind_param(uint32_t col_index, T&& param)
    {
        bind_param_impl(col_index, std::forward(param), 
                        std::is_integral<std::remove_reference_t<T>>());
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    void bind_param_impl(uint32_t col_index, T&& param, std::true_type)
    {
        statement->setNumber(col_index, oracle::occi::Number(param));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void bind_param_impl(uint32_t col_index, T&& param, std::false_type)
    {
        statement->setString(col_index, std::forward(param));
    }

    OracleConnection::StatementWrapper statement;
};
```

And then I wrote following client code to test it:

```
OraclePreparedStatement stmt;
auto col_index = 1;
stmt.bind_param(col_index++, 15);
stmt.bind_param(col_index++, std::string("test string"));
```

But it fails to compile. Both calls to bind_param method cause compile errors:

> error: no matching function for call to 'forward(int&)'
>   error: no matching function for call to 'forward(std::basic_string&)'

Why does forwarding params fail to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::forward` is intentionally written in such a way that you must explicitly specify the template argument—it couldn't possibly work without that. So just do so:

```
bind_param_impl(col_index, std::forward<T>(param), 
                std::is_integral<std::remove_reference_t<T>>());
```

and

```
statement->setString(col_index, std::forward<T>(param));
```

The reason is that for `std::forward` to work, it needs to know whether `T` itself was a reference or not. Note that since `param` is always an lvalue, there's no way `std::forward` could be written without you giving it explicit access to `T`.

Comment: Oh sure, I have misstype in code which I failed to recognize. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the deduced type to `std::forward()`. In your case you'd use `std::forward<T>(param)`.